# how to calculate one value is in the some range in r?

Tags: r

I have a vector which is interval

```
a=c((0.5)-rnorm(1,1,0.5),(0.5)+rnorm(1,1,0.5))
```

I want to repeat generate a 100 interval like above, and calculate how

many times (proportion) 1 appears in these 100 samples.

for example:-0.9243532 0.7800040. 1 is not in this interval. so return false. -0.6741866 1.4794725. 1 is  in this interval , so return true. I want the proportion of 100 of them. the ratio :  # of true/100

May be show how to calculate the bollean result for 1 is in one interval is also help

Answer (score 2):

We can use `replicate` in `base R`

```
m1 <- t(replicate(100, c((0.5)-rnorm(1,1,0.5),(0.5)+rnorm(1,1,0.5)), simplify = TRUE))
mean(m1[,1] <=1 & m1[,2] > 1)
[1] 0.8
```

Comment: Thanks but how to calculate the proportion of 1 in in the range for this 100 samples.

Comment: @hardworker try `mean(replicate(100, c((0.5)-rnorm(1,1,0.5),(0.5)+rnorm(1,1,0.5)), simplify = TRUE) == 1)`

Comment: I mean for the confidence interval we draw. for example:-0.9243532  0.7800040. 1 is not here. so return false. -0.6741866  1.4794725. 1 is here , so return true. I want the proportion of 100 of them. the ratio # of true/100

Answer (score 2):

you may also use map_lgl

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
map_lgl(replicate(100, c((0.5)-rnorm(1,1,0.5),(0.5)+rnorm(1,1,0.5)), simplify = FALSE), ~ 1 >= .x[1]  & 1 <= .x[2])
#>   [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [13]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [25]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [37]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [49]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [61]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [73]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [85]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [97]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

For proportion

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
sum(map_lgl(replicate(n, c((0.5)-rnorm(1,1,0.5),(0.5)+rnorm(1,1,0.5)), simplify = FALSE), ~ 1 >= .x[1]  & 1 <= .x[2]))/n
#> [1] 0.86
```

Answer (score 1):

Your math representation actually can be simplified a bit and you can try the code below

```
> mean(replicate(100, prod(0.5 + rnorm(2, 1, 0.5) * c(-1, 1)) < 0))
[1] 0.85
```

---

If you want to speed up, you can try

```
> n <- 100
> mean(do.call(`*`, split(0.5 + rnorm(2 * n, 1, 0.5) * c(-1, 1), c(1, 2))) < 0)
[1] 0.84
```